# Chrome extension notification's settings button is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

chrome extension's notification box has settings button. How to handle it? I can't hide it anyway. Why it doesn't work?

Here is my code in backgound.js:

```
chrome.notifications.create('', {
    title: options.title || 'Extension name',
    message: options.message || 'message !',
    iconUrl: options.iconUrl || 'icons/icon.png',
    type: options.type || 'basic',
  });
```

Anybody have an idea to handle settings button(icon)?

Comment: This button isn't related to the API. It's the built-in functionality of the browser or OS, you can't customize it.

Comment: @wOxxOm. at the moment it appears, but if someone click it doesn't happen anything. How to workaround it?

Comment: There's no way. This is probably a bug in the browser or OS.

Comment: @wOxxOm got it, actually I thought about chrome's bug, but i hope to find some workaround solution. thank you.